# How to Run Multiple Node.JS Version projects on the same machine on Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx

Tags: node.js, linux

Is it possible to have two or more different NodeJS versions and run at the same time?

Having 3 different versions on the same machine. For example:

```
Project 1: Run with 12 NodeJS version
Project 2: Run with 14 NodeJS version
Project 3: Run with 16 NodeJS version etc
```

I have a Linux 18.04 LTS server running with Nginx.
Now I am using one version with pm2.

So far the closest solution to my problem is to use nvm.
But nvm can install many versions but can use one version at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NVM for that. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. Use `nvm run` or `nvm exec`

nvm run - executes node on a specific version, so: nvm run 10 npm start is equivalent to `node npm start` (with version 10 of node installed).

You can also use `nvm exec` - executing a command on a specific version:

```
$ nvm exec 10 npm -v
Running node v10.0.0 (npm v6.0.0)
6.0.0
$ nvm exec 6 npm -v
Running node v6.10.3 (npm v3.10.10)
3.10.10
```

Comment: Did that works for the Linux server, with Nginx? It seems promising.